# Planting shrubs on a gently sloped landscape.

Tags: landscaping, shrubs

I have a couple shrubs I want to plant on a slanted landscape; nothing severe, maybe 10 degrees.  Should I plant perpendicular to the ground, or perpendicular to an imaginary level surface?  If it makes a difference, if I plant it perpendicular to the ground, the top of the shrub will be angled directly east towards the sunrise.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Plants will grow up to the light.  I recommend planting them perpendicular to the imaginary level surface. Anything else would look odd as the alternative is not seen in nature.

What will help is building a small ring of soil on the downhill side of the shrub and applying a few inches of organic mulch all round.

- this will capture and retain rain or groundwater moving downhill
- reduce chances of soil erosion and compaction
- the mulch will reduce weeding